# Font Awesome icons not rendering when I use PHP echo?

Tags: php, html, mysql, font-awesome

I'm trying to set up a menu list which pulls an array from a mysql query and uses a foreach to echo out each list element.

I'm using *font awesome*, and for some reason when I place the `<i>` elements inside of an echo line, the icons do not render. Other icons on the same page are rendering just fine.

I've verified that all of the `CSS` files are being included properly.

Here is the block of code, you can see that I am generating some icon names using `str_replace()`, however there are other icons in the echo that are static.

I'm pulling my hair out here.

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM outageupdates ORDER BY timestamp");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{

   $time = strtotime($row[timestamp]);
   $time = date("H:i", $time);
   $icon = str_replace("Internal", "fa-user", $row[type]);
   $icon = str_replace("External", "fa-user-times", $row[type]);
   echo '<li><a href="outageupdates.php"><i class="fa ' . $icon . '"></i>' . $row[agentname] . ' - ' . $row[type] . '<small class="pull-right"><i class="fa fa-clock"></i>' . $time . '</small></a></li>';
}
```

Comment: What icons do you mean, are you talking about the glyphicons?

Comment: The FontAwesome ones, though I believe they are both rendered with the <i> tag.

Answer (score 0):

What's happening is you're re-assigning `$icon` with an invalid icon class string if `$row['type']` contains anything other than *"External"*.

Say `$row['type']` (and don't forget to use quotes for your array keys), contains *"Internal"*. After

```
$icon = str_replace("Internal", "fa-user", $row['type']);
```

`$icon` will be *"fa-user"*. Then, after

```
$icon = str_replace("External", "fa-user-times", $row['type']);
```

`$icon` will be *"Internal"*.

Assuming `$row['type']` may only be either *"Internal"* or *"External"*, I'd use something like this instead

```
$icon = $row['type'] == 'Internal' ? 'fa-user' : 'fa-user-times';
```

---

Alternatively, you could use a switch statement if you have other *types*

```
switch($row['type']) {
    case 'Internal':
        $icon = 'fa-user';
        break;
    case 'External':
        $icon = 'fa-user-times';
        break;
    case 'Admin':
        $icon = 'fa-cogs';
        break;
    default:
        $icon = 'fa-question-circle';
}
```

Comment: That did the trick, thanks! 

I'm still pretty new to this, never used the switch statement before. Thanks for explaining it to me, as I've been using the str_replace() function in similar instances :$